# How to remove space between ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I want to do a 'pacman' game on Android Studio for a school project. We have an activity who have a ConstraintLayout in which I add programmatically the image view. I get the screen size in pixel and resize the imageViews in a pixel.
I have already tried to use relativeLayout with no success.

```
// Récupère taille écran
float screenHeight = 0;
float screenWidth = 0;

WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) 
this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;


ConstraintLayout linearLayout1 = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainView);
for(int x=0;x<31;x++) {
    for(int i=0;i<28;i++)
    {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);

        image.setMinimumWidth((int)screenHeight/31);
        image.setMinimumHeight((int)screenWidth/28);
        image.setX(screenWidth/28*i);
        image.setY(screenHeight/31*x);
        image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);
        linearLayout1.addView(image);
    }
}
```

I also tried to do this :

```
image.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
image.setCropToPadding(true);
```

What I actually have

[image]

What I would like to have

[image: enter imagadvance!tion here]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Your drawable download having padding .. this seems like an design issue .

Comment: you had used fixed value (/31 ,/28) to your image view.  that should be dynamic as per different screen size. and you are adding just images what ever you created in side >ConstraintLayout . That didn't make much sense.refer this one https://github.com/VictorAlbertos/Pacman

Comment: the /31,/28 are the row and column because all the imageView are going to be in a table. And sadly we can't use unity to make our app.